# Overlay a UIView on both a UINavigationBar and a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Essentially i want to display a notification just beneath the UINavigationController, covering the area that would be occupied by the top most UIViewController's view. However i want the background image to extend upwards and partly cover the UINavigationBar

The finished product should hopefully look like the below
[image]

The trick comes in that i only want this to apply to certain views with the view Hierarchy, so attacking the problem by using `[UIApplication keyWindow]` might not be the best idea. Also i assume that by using views outside of the private `UINavigationTransitionView` won't be part of the view transition animation, leaving my view on top of the controller beneath when this one is popped.

The view of the topmost view controller doesn't help either, as it's frame is terminates at the base of `UINavigationBar`, meaning arrow won't overlap the `UINavigationBar`

Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems that you are facing the problem with `Navigation Bar` only as that will not allow to overlap the View.

This is tricky part....
Just use the **Custom back button set the image over it in left of the Navigation bar Button**

[image]

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [self.navigationController navigationBar];   
UIButton *btn;
btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 2, 100, 48)];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[bar addSubview:btn];
[btn release];
```

This is surely going to help you & solve all your Queries for the same ....[image]

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Problem is I wanted to animate the appearance. Having to animate two views and keep the animations in sync seems problematic.

Comment: Yes for that case it will create some trouble....Now there seeems to be no alternative other than using you own custom Navigation Bar.You can use try for it.Hope that could solve